# Empty hash declaration

Tags: perl, variables, variable-declaration

I've never known the difference, if there is one, between the following:

```
my %hash;
my %hash = ();
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some languages, new variables are provided uninitialized. In Perl, scalars are created undefined, and array and hashes are created empty.

The second is wasteful. Assigning an empty list to an empty hash has no effect.

Comment: That was my hunch, but I see it so much that I assumed there was a purpose!

Answer (score 4):

You're quite correct. There's no difference. Declaring a hash (or array) creates an empty data structure.

This is slightly at odds with declaration of scalars - a scalar can be declared but undefined. This doesn't really make sense for a hash or array, so it makes no difference.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $scalar;
my $scalar2 = '';

print Dumper \$scalar;
print Dumper \$scalar2;

my %hash;
my %hash2 = ();
print Dumper \%hash;
print Dumper \%hash2;

my @array;
my @array2 = ();

print Dumper \@array;
print Dumper \@array2;
```

If you look at the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) docs, you see:

"Use of defined on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated. It used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been allocated. This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl. You should instead use a simple test for size:"

Comment: Re "This is slightly at odds with declaration of scalars - a scalar can be declared but undefined", Arrays and hashes can similarly have no array allocated. `perl -MDevel::Peek -e'@a="x"; @a=(); Dump(\@a); undef @a; Dump(\@a);'`

Comment: The scalar equivalent of `@a=();` is `$a=undef;`.

Comment: Hmm, but you can do `defined` on `$scalar`, to test, but you can't do the same on `@a`.

Comment: Not so. `defined($scalar)` checks if the variable has values. `0+@a` does that for arrays. In fact, you have it backwards. You can do more with arrays than with scalars. `defined(@array)` checks if the array has a buffer allocated, but you can't do that for scalars (from Perl).

Comment: `defined(@array)` gets me a warning that it's deprecated ;)

Comment: Yeah, cause it's a useless thing to check, which is why you never noticed you couldn't do it for scalars.